# Create hierarchy column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, networkx

I have got a dataframe like this:

```
    part part_parent
0  part1         NaN
1  part2       part1
2  part3       part2
3  part4       part3
4  part5       part2
```

I need to add an additional column hierarchy like this:

```
    part part_parent                hierarchy
0  part1         NaN                    part1
1  part2       part1             part1/part2/
2  part3       part2       part1/part2/part3/
3  part4       part3  part1/part2/part3/part4
4  part5       part2        part1/part2/part5
```

Dict to create input/output dataframes:

```
from numpy import nan

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'part': {0: 'part1', 1: 'part2', 2: 'part3', 3: 'part4', 4: 'part5'},
 'part_parent': {0: nan, 1: 'part1', 2: 'part2', 3: 'part3', 4: 'part2'}})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'part': {0: 'part1', 1: 'part2', 2: 'part3', 3: 'part4', 4: 'part5'},
 'part_parent': {0: nan, 1: 'part1', 2: 'part2', 3: 'part3', 4: 'part2'},
 'hierarchy': {0: 'part1',
  1: 'part1/part2/',
  2: 'part1/part2/part3/',
  3: 'part1/part2/part3/part4',
  4: 'part1/part2/part5'}})
```

*NOTE:* I've seen a couple of threads related to `NetworkX` to solve this issue but I'm not able to do so.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using `networkx`.  It treats `nan` as the root node, and finds the shortest path to each node based on that.

```
import networkx as nx

def find_path(net, source, target):
    # Adjust this as needed (in case multiple paths are present)
    # or error handling in case a path doesn't exist
    path = nx.shortest_path(net, source, target)
    return "/".join(list(path)[1:])

net = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, "part", "part_parent")
df1["hierarchy"] = [find_path(net, nan, node) for node in df1["part"]]
```

---

```
    part part_parent                hierarchy
0  part1         NaN                    part1
1  part2       part1              part1/part2
2  part3       part2        part1/part2/part3
3  part4       part3  part1/part2/part3/part4
4  part5       part2        part1/part2/part5
```

The formatting of the path is contrived for this example, if more robust error-handling or multiple path formatting is needed, the path finder will have to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive approach. It uses a Series that contains the parents for each element to find a given parent and walks back to the original parent until it finds NaN. At this point it returns the hierarchy.

*NB. This will not work if you have a circular network or undefined parents (the latter can easily be fixed is needed)*

```
import pandas as pd

parents = df1.set_index('part')['part_parent']
def hierarchy(e):
    if not isinstance(e, list):
        return hierarchy([e])
    parent = parents[e[0]]
    if pd.isna(parent):
        return '/'.join(e)
    return hierarchy([parent]+e)

df2 = df1.copy()
df2['hierarchy'] = df1['part'].apply(hierarchy)
```